# Splitting background horizontally in half with different colors

Tags: html, css, background

Is there a way to archive div background like this with CSS

[image]

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

```css
.box {
  background: linear-gradient(165deg, #41c7b4 54.5%, #ff7c4a 55%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 205px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is! You can use :pseudo-classes (`:before` and `:after`).

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #41c7b4;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -25px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  background: #ff7c4a;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```